# android:layout_width="0dp" does not work for ScrollView in a fragment

Tags: android-layout, android-scrollview

The ScrollView in the following layout does not show at all:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/FragmentLayout"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:orientation="vertical">
...
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/DodgerBlue" />

            <TableLayout style="@style/TableLayoutFieldGroup">

 ...
            </TableLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableLayout style="@style/TableLayoutFieldGroup">

                </TableLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

However, it works perfectly when I use android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of android:layout_width="0dp" for the ScrollView.   I tried android:layout_width="0dp" because Android Studio keeps recommending it.

Could anyone offer a tip on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayou
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayou>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TableLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ScrollView
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TableLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

@Hong Use ConstraintLayout

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  As I wrote in my question, I can easily solve the problem by using layout_width="match_parent". My question is about why layout_width="0dp" does not work in this case.  It is more for my education than solving any problem.